# send multiple emails

Tags: asp.net, email, send

i am sending email to the users using smtp client and MailMessage class.

i have been adding the addresses of multiple receivers in the to property of the object of MailMessage class. the problem is that the receiver can see the email addresses of other receipents. is there any way to hide the email addresses of other receipents.

i mean setting some property or something like that.

otherwise i will be left with only option to send individual email to the users.

any help
plesae

Answer (score 1):

Add the receivers as a Bcc (blind carbon copy/copies circulating) address instead of a To address.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anyway to get around this. You either send out single emails addressed to each recipient or add the list of recipients to BCC and send it once. The problem with the latter is, I believe that most spam filters will block the email.

Answer (score 1):

Emails are always sent individually. I would recommend you go that route, instead of using a BCC.

Here's the difference.  Let's say you put 10 people on a BCC. The SmtpClient sends 1 message to your relay server. However, your relay server reads those 10 recipients, and sends out 10 individual emails, one to each recipient.

Since 10 emails are being sent anyway, I would recommend you creating 10 separate emails in your code, and send them out.

Now, does it initially take longer to do this? Yes. It will take 10x as long to send out that same email, from your code.

However, the benefit, is that you are less susceptible of being labelled a BCC spammer.